# Struts 2 - Adding to a nested collection

Tags: struts2, type-conversion, form-submit

So I have a student class that is my action class

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Student extends ActionSupport{
    private Vector<AcaClass> classes;

    public Student(){}

    public Vector<Class> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public void setClasses(Vector<Class> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public void addClass(AcaClass acaClass){
            this.classes.add(acaClass)
    }  


}
```

and I have a AcaClass

```
public class AcaClass {

    private Term term;
    private String grade;
    private String description;
    //public 

    public AcaClass(){}

        //Getters and setters for all data members
}
```

Is it possible to add a class to to the student's collection of classes? I feel like that I would have to do a form submission and then some type conversion to turn the form fields into the AcaClass bean. If this is possible, how many levels of collections can I go (i.e. Add a class to a collection of students thats in a collection of colleges thats in a collection of universities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OGNL will do the conversion for you.

See this very similar question. [Struts2 - Edit Composite Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857965/struts2-edit-composite-object)